# Makefile not picking up new static library for linking

Tags: c, linux, makefile, gnu

I have a project which is building successfully until i added a new static library, and now the `Makefile` is showing `undefined reference to` error for all functions coming from new static library.

Before integrating new library `libmm.a`

```
TARGET:tcpstack.exe pkt_gen.exe
LIBS=-lpthread -lcli -lrt -L CommandParser -lcli     << dependent libraries
tcpstack.exe:testapp.o ${OBJS} CommandParser/libcli.a
${CC} ${CFLAGS} testapp.o ${OBJS}  ${LIBS} -o tcpstack.exe
@echo "Build Finished"
```

Now I add a new Library LinuxMemoryManager/libmm.a as by doing following modification to above lines :

```
TARGET:tcpstack.exe pkt_gen.exe
LIBS=-lpthread -lcli -lrt -L CommandParser -lcli -L LinuxMemoryManager -lmm
tcpstack.exe:testapp.o ${OBJS} CommandParser/libcli.a LinuxMemoryManager/libmm.a
${CC} ${CFLAGS} testapp.o ${OBJS}  ${LIBS} -o tcpstack.exe
@echo "Build Finished"
```

The library libmm.a is being built successfully, but executable creation is failing with `undefined reference to`  error for all functions coming from new `libmm.a` library.

Kindly help what am i missing here.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code.

Comment: have you added header files properly?

Comment: @Jarvis__-_-__ yes.

Comment: Should be no space between option -L and the path, similar to option -l.

Comment: Tried that, still same problem. When i add an object file of the libmm.o library to list of OBJS , then it compiles. But that undo the purpose of linking with library.

Comment: Spaces after the `-L` (or the `-I` for that matter) work fine.  Please format your question correctly so it's easier to read as a makefile, and please show us both the link command line that make printed and at least some of the actual error messages (please use cut and paste, don't paraphrase).